# How do I change the size of the title bar?

Tags: 2013, css

I want to change the size of the bar that contains the navigation area in the Oslo theme.

For clarification, I want to change the height of this bar:

[image]

**Edit:** I have figured out that the element in question has id #titleAreaBox, but it seems as though you cannot shrink its height past the default of 134px. I am only able to increase the height.

Comment: You can inspect element in browser, then apply your custom `CSS` to change the height.

Comment: I've tried to inspect it, but I can't figure out what element I have to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find your element by using the browser's developer tools, and then modify the CSS according to your needs. You will most likely want to change the `height` attribute of the element.

The below screencap shows how you can use the browser's element selector tool to locate your elements. The screencap is from Google Chrome.
[image]

Comment: I understand that and I've tried it, but I can't seem to locate the correct element. Every time I insert CSS to change the elements that I've found with this method, there is no change.

EDIT: I found it using this method. I thought I had already tried `titleAreaBox`, but it was in fact the correct element. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you cannot shrink the area past the default of 134px. Any ideas?

Comment: There might be another style adjustment blocking that, so you'd need to override it first. You can try adding `!Important` to the change (as e.g. `height: 100px !Important`. Also you can try defining the minimum-height as `min-height: 50 px !Important`.

Comment: I tried both of those and neither worked. Do you think I need to also change the size of other elements around it? If so, which ones?

Comment: I can only give a vague answer: it depends, maybe. It depends a lot on your current customizations. I can't reproduce the exact page you have, so it's not possible to tell the exact solution. I'd suggest to inspect the surrounding elements' styling and give attempts to the surrounding elements.

Comment: I would think that the entire bar at the top is just configured from the master page, and I'm using the Oslo master page. Do you think you could try out the default Oslo master page and let me know if you figure it out?

Answer (score 1):

Try this CSS :

```
#s4-titlerow {
     height: 140px !Important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#s4-titlerow {
    height: 800px;
}
```

Comment: This did not work. Why put the s4?

Comment: because that is the entire id of the element. `s4-titlerow`

Comment: Well I'm able to change the height of the element with `#titleAreaBox {height: 800px;}`, but I can't shrink the height of the titleAreaBox past the default of 134px. Do you think I have to also change `s4-titlerow` to match?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look for this element, which affects the height of the area:

```
.ms-core-navigation {
    margin-top: 100px !important;
}
```