# Custom Action id of element - how to get to C# code

Tags: custom-actions

I have got A custom action in Open Menu. But i must get ID of element. How could I get ID when I clicked three dots on C# code:

Comment: I've shown in another answer how you can locate elements (and their IDs) by using Chrome. Find it [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218059/how-do-i-change-the-size-of-the-title-bar/218065#218065).

Comment: But I need a ID of clicked element.

Comment: When a button/element/anything is clicked, its ID doesn't necessarily change. If it's designed like that, then it might change, but for what I've witnesses, in SharePoint's context clicked elements don't usually have a dynamically changing ID.

Comment: Yes I know that, but how could I get in C# code. I must always use javascript ? or there is a method to get IDs.

Comment: On the C# language.

Comment: Sorry, but not able to answer to that question. It seems you didn't specify all necessary information in the original question, so you should edit it to add more details to it.

Comment: But how to language C# clicked element. Only that I want ID of element.

Answer (score 1):

**You can't do it using C#**. You can use Javascript code to get the item ID of selected Item. check my sample code :

```
var ItemID;
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);
var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("List_title");
var item;
for (item in selectedItems)
{
    var mySelItem = list.getItemById(selectedItems[item].id);
    ItemID=selectedItems[item].id;
}
if(selectedItems.length == '1')
{
  alert("Selected Items is is: "+ ItemID);
}
else{ alert("Please Select only one item"); }
```

**OR** some Reference : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/e34e59eb-dc77-47e5-8f42-5d27b6ae925b/sharepoint-2010-get-id-of-selected-list-item-using-c

Comment: Thanks, but how to fire the javascript ?

Comment: There is a mistaqe, because it not showing me after loop for.

Comment: using ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(params).. you can call javascript code in your code behind file. MSDN ; https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have corrected my code

Comment: I don't cnow why, but when I set "SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context);" the javascript don't show me.