# remove space using css in sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

i need to add custom html page in a webpage to show the background etc. i was able to hide navigation bar title bar etc using css. But i cant seems to remove the below space from the menu bar and the right of the window.

[image]

Can someone suggest a Css to expand the width to 100% so that the space can  be removed ?

Comment: div.ms-cui-TabRowRight{padding-right:0px;}

Comment: It entirely depends what's the element's name and other identifiers. I have given [here an answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/218059/how-do-i-change-the-size-of-the-title-bar/218065#218065) which shows how you can find your element you should adjust with your CSS. It might be that there's a border you need to hide, or indeed you need to expand the body-area's width or such - you can find it out only by inspecting the page's structure.

Comment: i have identified <div class="ms-wikicontent ms-rtestate-field" style="padding-right: 10px;"> to be the problem how do i remove the padding right style:10px

Comment: make it 0px !Important;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you detailed in the comments that the relevant element forming the space area is `<div class="ms-wikicontent ms-rtestate-field" style="padding-right: 10px;">`, you need to add a `padding-right: 0px` for the element in question with an `!Important` rule to override the HTML-defined style attribute.

So, add the following CSS:

```
div.ms-wikicontent.ms-rtestate-field {
   padding-right: 0px !Important;
}
```

Comment: yes that was it . i was trying  .ms-wikicontent.ms-rtestate-field {
   padding-right: 0px !Important;
}